# how to get id of selected item value from selectOneMenu in jsf?

Tags: jsf-2

I have dropdown of categories. On selecting particular category, I have rendered another dropdown of subcategories of that category. I want id of selected subcategory.But I am not getting it.My code is:

```
 <tr>
     <td align="right">
          <h:outputText value="Select Main Category:"></h:outputText>
     </td>
     <td>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="cmbcategory" value="#{categoryBean.categoryID}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Category" >
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select Category--" itemValue="0"></f:selectItem>
               <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.categories}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.categoryName}" itemValue="#{item.categoryID}"></f:selectItems>
               <f:ajax event="valueChange" render="cmbsubcategory"  immediate="true" listener="#{categoryBean.SubcategoriesByCategory()}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
     </td>
     <td><h:message for="cmbcategory"></h:message></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td align="right">
          <h:outputText value="Select Sucategory:"></h:outputText>
      </td>
      <td>
           <h:selectOneMenu id="cmbsubcategory" value="#{categoryBean.subCategoryID}" required="true" requiredMessage="Select Subcategory">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select Subcategory--" itemValue="0"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.SubcategoriesByCategory()}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.subcategoryID}" itemValue="#{item.subcategoryID}"></f:selectItems>

           </h:selectOneMenu>
      </td>
      <td><h:message for="cmbsubcategory"></h:message></td>
 </tr>
```

And my bean is:

```
public int getCategoryID() {
        return CategoryID;
    }

    public void setCategoryID(int CategoryID) {
        this.CategoryID = CategoryID;
    }


    public String getCategoryName() {
        return CategoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String CategoryName) {
        this.CategoryName = CategoryName;
    }

    public Collection<Category> getCategories() {
        categories=abr.getAllCategory();
        return categories;
    }

    public Collection<Subcategory> SubcategoriesByCategory()
    {
        System.out.print("catid...... "+CategoryID);
        subcats= abr.searchAllSubcategoriesByCategory(CategoryID);

        return subcats;

//            +"size....."+ subcats.size());
     }

    public String getSubCatName() {
        return SubCatName;
    }

    public void setSubCatName(String SubCatName) {
        this.SubCatName = SubCatName;
    }

    public int getSubCategoryID() {
        System.out.print("subcatid...... "+SubCategoryID);
        return SubCategoryID;
    }

    public void setSubCategoryID(int SubCategoryID) {
        this.SubCategoryID = SubCategoryID;
    }

    public Collection<Subcategory> getSubcats() {
        return subcats;
    }

    public void setSubcats(Collection<Subcategory> subcats) {
        this.subcats = subcats;
    }



    public void setCategories(Collection<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up a property getter with an action method. A getter should return the property and an action method should be `void` or return a `String`.

Change

```
public Collection<Subcategory> SubcategoriesByCategory() {
  ..
}
```

to

```
public void searchSubcats() {
  subcats= abr.searchAllSubcategoriesByCategory(CategoryID);
}
```

and call this method in your ajax request:

```
<f:ajax .. listener="#{categoryBean.searchSubcats}"/>
```

The selectItems in the second drow-down then need to reference the getter for subcats:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{categoryBean.subcats}" ... />
```

Comment: Can I call method in value of <f:selectItems value=""> ?

Comment: The `value` attribute takes a ValueExpression (which is a bean property with corresponding getters and setters). But you cannot put an action method as `value`.